# How do I use Automapper to map changes to an existing collection?

Tags: c#, generics, mapping, viewmodel, automapper

I have some fairly straightforward code to apply user changes on a collection in a viewmodel to a collection in a model.

```
public void Apply(ViewModelListItem source, ICollection<ModelListItem> dest)
{
    //user added and removed an item before saving, do nothing
    if (source.Insert && source.Delete) return;

    //user added an item
    if (source.Insert)
    {
        dest.Add(Mapper.Map<T>(source));
    }

    //user deleted an item
    else if (source.Delete)
    {
        //Using custom Equals implementation that compares PK
        dest.Remove(dest.FirstOrDefault(destItem => source.Equals(destItem)));
    }

    //user modified or did not alter an item
    else
    {
        //Using custom Equals implementation that compares PK
        Mapper.Map(source, dest.FirstOrDefault(destItem => source.Equals(destItem)));
    }
}
```

...

```
foreach (var item in MyViewModel.MyCollection)
{
    Apply(item, MyModel.MyCollection);
}
```

I use this pattern in multiple locations in my code, so I was looking for a way to reuse the code in a generic way. Does Automapper have a way to simply pass references to the source/destination and let me run my own setting logic on it? If not, is there any other way I can make this code generic so I don't have to write it for every new viewmodel?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Added my solution as an answer. Note: I ended up dropping automapper for other reasons, but still use the same idea for mapping collections, just minus the automapper integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution:

Viewmodel's base class:

```
public abstract class ListItemViewModel<T>
{
    public bool Insert { get; set; }
    public bool Delete { get; set; }

    public abstract bool Equals(T model);

    public virtual void OnRemove(T model) { }
    public virtual void OnAdd(T model) { }
    public virtual void OnEdit(T model) { }
}
```

Helper function:

```
public static class MapConfiguration
{
    public static void MapCollection<T>(IEnumerable<ListItemViewModel<T>> source, ICollection<T> dest)
    {
        foreach (var sourceItem in source)
        {
            //user added and removed an item before saving, do nothing
            if (sourceItem.Insert && sourceItem.Delete) continue;

            //user added an item
            if (sourceItem.Insert)
            {
                var destItem = Mapper.Map<T>(sourceItem);
                sourceItem.OnAdd(destItem);
                dest.Add(destItem);
            }

            //user deleted an item
            else if (sourceItem.Delete)
            {
                //Using custom Equals implementation that compares PK
                var destItem = dest.First(d => sourceItem.Equals(d));
                sourceItem.OnRemove(destItem);
                dest.Remove(destItem);
            }

            //user modified or did not alter an item
            else
            {
                //Using custom Equals implementation that compares PK
                var destItem = dest.First(d => sourceItem.Equals(d));
                sourceItem.OnEdit(destItem);
                Mapper.Map(sourceItem, destItem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To implement:

- Create a view model class that inherits from `ListItemViewModel` where T is the model type
- Implement the `Equals(T model)` method, so the helper function can match existing elements in the enumerable
- Add a generic enumerable property with the ListItemViewModel's inherited type to your main view model

When you configure automapper, you can now use the following:

```
.ForMember(m => m.MyList, opt => opt.Ignore())
.AfterMap((vm, m) => MapConfiguration.MapCollection(vm.MyList, m.MyList))
```

This code will do the following:

- Add new items to your collection if the `Insert` flag is set
- Remove items from your collection if the `Remove` flag is set
- Perform Automapper mapping if neither flag is set

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection). It handles all CRUD operations on collections automatically:

> Will Add/Update/Delete items from a preexisting collection object based on user defined equivalency between the collection's generic item type from the source collection and the destination collection